# update query based on select query

Tags: mysql, select

**exactly I want to write "UPDATE" and "SELECT" into one query.**

I need check for setting a field.
for this action, I used SELECT query on TABLE1 and then if it dose not have result, another filed of TABLE2 is updated.
FOR EX:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con , "select sID FROM schedule where (dayID = '{$this->dID}' AND patientID = '')");
$rep = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if(count($rep) == 0)
mysqli_query($con,"update days set schFilled = 1  where dID = '{$this->dID}'");
else   
mysqli_query($con,"update days set schFilled = 0 where dID = '{$this->dID}'");
```

I would like run those with ONE query, in fact I want something like this:(whit CASE to write second update too)

```
update days set schFilled = 0 where( (select sID FROM schedule where (dayID = '{$this->dID}' AND patientID = '') IS NULL) AND (dID = '{$this->dID}'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "UPDATE days SET schFilled = 
                           CASE
                           WHEN (SELECT IF(EXISTS(select sID FROM schedule where (dayID = '{$this->dID}' AND patientID = '' AND hour != 0)), 1, 0))
                            THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                            END
                            where dID = '{$this->dID}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

use the mysqli object like this:

```
 $res = mysqli_query($con , "your select");
 if($res->num_rows === 0) {
      //no res
 }
 else {
      //else
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but I want "update" and "select" in one query, with if!

Comment: like this: update days set schFilled = 0 where( (select sID FROM schedule where (dayID = '{$this->dID}' AND patientID = '') IS NULL) AND (dID = '{$this->dID}'))